# Apache Tika OSGi bundle fail when doing mvn install

Tags: apache, maven, apache-tika

I am trying to install Apache Tika Toolkit on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I then go to the folder where Apache Tika is and execute mvn install from the command line.  Yet, that produce a failure error that says:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.10:verify (default) on project
tika-bundle: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\tika-1.3\tika-bundle\target\failsafe-report
s for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

I have been looking on the web for a while but nothing so far.  Any idea? Thanks. 
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason why you're building the source, rather than just having Maven download the binary versions for you?

Comment: That's a good question.  Actually, the instructions for the web application I am installing is asking me to install the JAR file for Apache Tika in C:/Program Files/tika.  Any idea on how to do that? Just copy the JAR file there?

Comment: The Tika App Jar or all of Tika? If the former, just [go to the download page and get it there](http://tika.apache.org/download.html)

Comment: The Tika App Jar.  I already have it on my computer.  Now how do I install it?

Comment: It's a standalone runnable jar. Just double click and it'll launch the GUI, or run it on the command line with `java -jar tika-app-1.3.jar --help` to see the options it supports